# How do I detect if a program is running within a PAR archive?

Tags: perl, zip, par

I'm working on a large Perl application which gets bundled with [PAR](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR), along with a bunch of support files.

When the app is running within PAR, I can use `PAR::read_file` to get at these various files inside the archive. However, while I'm developing, I don't want to have to re-PAR the whole application every time I tweak some code.

Is there a way that I can tell if the script is running within PAR or not at runtime, so I can choose to load the file from the PAR archive or the regular filesystem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[PAR::Environment](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/PAR::Environment) can probably offer some clues:

> PAR uses various environment variables both during the building process of executables or PAR archives and the ***use*** of them.

...

> `PAR_0`
>
> If the running program is run from within a PAR archive or pp-produced executable, this variable contains the name of the extracted program (i.e. .pl file).

Comment: @tsee Thank you very much for verifying and thank very much for PAR and pp. They have been a great help to me ever since I started using them.